# Astronomy/Astrophysics Project With C++/C/Python

Tags: data-analysis, python, n-body-simulations, algorithm, raw-data

I am a Computer Science Engineering student, in the 1st year of college. I'm insanely interested in making a project regarding astronomy/astrophysics but I don't know where to begin from. I know C, C++, Python(not Scipy,Numpy or Astropy, but the basics. But I'm willing to learn those too). Can someone please give me some insights on what do make/do which would satisfy my aptitude in this field? My C++ and C knowledge are almost up to date, and I know basics of python, with all the data structures and basic libraries of Python. I'm interested in simulation stuff, but I don't exactly have relevant resources to learn those.

Comment: Knowing how to write code that compiles and runs has nothing to do with knowing how to produce algorithms that simulate the system you  are interested in.

Comment: Hi @KumarTatsat, two kinds of projects come to mind that are related to Astronomy, 1) orbital simulators (seeing how planets, moons, spacecraft) move in space under the influence of their mutual gravity, and 2) visualizing how the planets, Sun, Moon, asteroids, etc. appear and move in the sky. Stack Exchange is a great place to ask specific questions, don't worry that this one was considered too broad, find something specific, do a little reading, find specific questions, then ask again! Try to add a bit of your own work to the question as well so people have a better idea how to best answer.

Comment: For orbit simulation, here are examples in python that range from [simple](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29286/7982) to [complicated](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23409/12102). For visualizing things in space and from Earth, you can try installing the python package [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) and have some fun.

Comment: For general discussion and questions you can also try the Stack Exchange chat rooms. For Astronomy SE it's [The Observatory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/815/the-observatory) and for Space Exploration SE it's [The Pod Bay](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay)